# Custom notification Android does not show up the same on different devices

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications

I'm trying to create a custom notification in Android using Xamarin.Android. The notification that I create dose not show up the same on different devices. This is the code that I'm using:

```
Notification.Buider not = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .SetTicker("Service started")
    .SetContentTitle("This is the title")
    .SetContentText("This is the content")
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);

Notification notification = not.Build();
notification.BigContentView=rv;
NotificationManager manager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
manager.Notify(0,notification);
```

If I run this on a Lenovo A319(which runs Android 4.4.2) the notification is show without inflating the `rv` variable, whereas If I run the app on Samsung Galaxy S7(Android 6.0.1) the notification is shown as the layout in the `rv` variable is describing it.

I want to know why the notification is not showing the same on different devices. It is caused by the android versions or is there something wrong with my code?

[image: Lenovo Android 4.4.2]
[image]

Comment: Could you show how the notification looks like in different devices?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Which one is your notification? I see on the first image "this is the title", but on the second?

Comment: Is the one with those 4 buttons (previous sign, play sign, next sign and random button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your CustomLayout, so I created mine "oneimg_twolbl.xml" with 2 TextViews and 1 ImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_list4_view" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_list4_view2" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image_list4_view" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I show this as custom notification by

```
        /////////////////////// custom notification /////////////////////////////////////
        RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(PackageName, Resource.Layout.oneimg_twolbl);
        v.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.text_list4_view, "Text 1");
        v.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.text_list4_view2, "Text 2");
        v.SetImageViewResource(Resource.Id.image_list4_view, Resource.Drawable.Icon);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
              new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
              .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
              .SetCustomBigContentView(v) //if API >= 16
              .SetContent(v)
              .SetAutoCancel(true);

        /////////////////////// custom notification to activity call /////////////////////////////////////

        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, this.Class);
        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(this.Class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent
                );
        mBuilder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        /////////////////////// end custom notification to activity call /////////////////////////////////////

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        // count allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.Notify(count++, mBuilder.Build());
        /////////////////////// end custom notification /////////////////////////////////////
```

You can look more here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this example! I also figured it out why my notification has different appearance. On Galaxy S7 the notification is shown on top so it appears in extended view mode, while on the lenovo the notificataion is shown the 3rd one so it is not in extended view mode, therefore it is limited to a height of 64 dp, and cannot inflate my layout file which I think it is like 160dp. Now do you know how to force notification to be always the first one?

Comment: Try to not call SetContentView but call only SetCustomBigContentView

Comment: Why? What is the difference between these two? I assume that SetCustomBigContentView shows the notification in expanded mode (when the notification is on top of the notifications panel and therefore the layout can occupe more than 64 dp in hieght) while the SetContentView shows the  notification in its standard form(the height is not greater than 64dp). Is there any other difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend you to write real code instead of a screen shot.

Second, here is a snippet of how to notify a user

```
   private void notifyUserOfDBupdate() {
    //Intents
    Intent Pdf_view = new Intent(this, //class to throw the user when they hit on notification\\.class);
    PendingIntent pdf_view = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, Pdf_view, 0);


    //Notification Manager
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    //The note
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setTicker("TickerTitle")
            .setContentTitle("content title")
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentText("content text")
            .setContentIntent(pdf_view).getNotification();


    //Execution
    noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    nm.notify(0, noti);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know this, but how do I make a custom notification? I want to design my own xml(or axml) file and that file to be my notification.